# Feasibility of Anti-Mass Weapons

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapons

I continued on searching for sci fi weapons that work under exotic physics which is not handwavium, and at least unobtainium, and I saw this comment:

*“Anti-Mass spheres. Bubbles of pure nothingness, the negative counterpart of mass itself.*

*Upon being created, the sphere immediately seeks out an object of equal mass and zips toward it at near light speed. When it makes contact, both disappear. For it to work, the exact mass of the target object needs to be known down to the quantum increments, but if you get it right there's no defense.”*

My question if such a thing of (**Anti-Mass**) or (**Pure Nothingness**) exists, and subsequently if the effects stated are real and possible.

I need not ask on how to build one, except if the first two answers confirms its existence.

Forum for this discussion: https://forums.sufficientvelocity.com/threads/create-science-fiction-weapons-based-on-exotic-physics.11280/

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it sounds like you're describing Antimatter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter

Comment: This was not my idea, but it does sound hella similar.

Comment: Pretty much every suggestion on the page you linked is made of magic and handwavium. At best they can be described as "science inspired" as they have scency-sounding buzzwords, but that's as close to reality or science that they get. They aren't scifi weapons. Just magic.

Comment: (I see that seems to be where you got your "particle decoupling" weapon ideas from too, which are also a load of cobblers. It'd save everyone a great deal of time if you didn't just enumerate every terrible idea from that source. The answers in every case will be "_No, they're not real_" and "_No, they're not possible_").

Comment: If negative mass existed, it would act like mass, with the gravity elements negated. The idea that it would seek out an identical amount of positive mass is just silly.

Comment: @NomadMaker Whether or not negative mass would accelerate to positive mass is subject to a debate between Hermann Bondi and William Bonnor. (Though it should be noted that it's an attraction to positive mass as a general whole, rather than something like a seek-and-destroy missile.)

Comment: @Halfthawed Sorry, I didn't say anything about its attraction to normal matter, merely that having it only seek out an identical mass of positive matter is ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

**Negative Mass**

Neither 'anti-mass' nor 'pure nothingness' are particularly meaningful terms, I suspect what the poster was talking about was something called 'negative mass' which exhibits some, but not all, of the characteristics you brought up. Negative mass accelerates towards a repelling force, which was theorized, and then discovered through some [unique experimentation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04055) by manipulating it's effective mass.

It doesn't annihilate matter, that's a property of anti-matter, not negative mass. It interacts weirdly with normal mass, as a runaway motion. Also, it'll have a really hard time hitting anything because it whatever positive mass it accelerates at will be accelerated away at the same rate to avoid violating the laws of conservation of energy. (Does that sound weird? It kind of is.)

That said, negative mass is theoretical, and the best we can do is simulate negative mass by dropping effective mass. It's not effective to weaponize at all.

Answer (score 0):

Building anti-matter is fairly 'easy' as we can do it with our current technology level, albeit we've only produced enough to basically boil tea. You might have heard of "positrons" which are the anti-matter particle for electrons. These are used a lot in medical technology as small amounts of positrons are fairly easy to come by.

For genuine anti-matter creation though you need a massive amount of energy to create it with a particle accelerator, and a storage device (a Penning trap which is fundamentally a portable particle accelerator) that keeps the antimatter from colliding with the real matter around before desired.

I would argue at the energy levels required for regular use either:

1. a source of cheap plentiful energy needs to be made available -

   - (for civilizations using it as a regular weapon this might be a moot point)
2. or there needs to be a compelling case to use an antimatter device over another destructive option

   - religion and philosophy
   - some corresponding incentivizing technology

Comment: Antimatter does not have negative mass, and negative mass is kind of essential in the question.